# BSOD 116 after installing nVidia drivers in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

System:

- Windows 7 64-bit SP1 with updates, fresh install
- Intel Core 2 Duo E4500
- 3GB RAM
- MSI GeForce 210 1GB (passive cooling)
- Abit IB9 motherboard (no integrated graphics)
- nothing overclocked

Everything works great with built-in VGA drivers, but after installing nVidia drivers
(no matter what version, tried various from 266.58 to 310.70 with clean uninstall/install)

system restarts to complete the drivers installation, and then gets BSOD (BCCode: 116) trying to boot.

Booting in safe mode and restoring VGA drivers makes it boot properly again.

I tried:

- testing memory with memtest
- disabling devices (sound & network) in BIOS
- cleaning dust

What can I do to install nVidia drivers?

Comment: Did you download drivers from MSI or nVidia?

Comment: From nVidia's site